# Procedure MySql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to do a procedure in MySql and I only work with Sql Server.
I tried many ways to do this procedures and I can't...
Someone can help me?

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE DictionaryInsert (

    IN Word VARCHAR(150),
    OUT IdWord INT(11)            

)   
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT IdWord IdWord FROM Dictionary WHERE Word = Word) THEN
            INSERT INTO 
                Dictionary
            (
                Word           
            )
            VALUES
            (
                Word
            );
    END IF


    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Comment: what have you tried? what failures have you had? what diagnostics are reported from mySql?

Comment: I'm trying to do a insert IF the word "X" not EXISTS.

Comment: then I think the diagnostics from mySql must be horrible - I can't believe you don't get any error messages at all.

Comment: this is the error:
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 16

Comment: Can I recommend that you use meaningful table and variable names?  Your statements mean nothing to me (and they'll mean nothing to you in 2 weeks).  Tables with variables names the same as the table names is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Note too that asking the same question for the 1000th time is not good practice. Prove that you have done some due diligence and search - SO has a plethora of questions about this subject already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1064

Comment: KevinDTimm.
I changed my table look:

CREATE PROCEDURE DictionaryInsert (
 
 IN Word VARCHAR(150),
 OUT IdWord INT(11)            
 
) 
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT IdWord IdWord FROM Dictionary WHERE Word = Word) THEN
   INSERT INTO 
    Dictionary
   (
    Word           
   )
   VALUES
   (
    Word
   );
 END IF


 SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE 
    PROCEDURE `DictionaryInsert`(OUT IdWord INT, IN NWord VARCHAR(150))
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT IdWord FROM Dictionary WHERE Word = NWord) THEN
            INSERT INTO Dictionary(Word) VALUES(NWord);
            SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() INTO IdWord;
        END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: So, as you can see - changing your variable names made identifying the mistakes in your procedure quite simple (and had nothing to do with MySql or your familiarity with SQL Server)